# How can I set reserved blocks for a NTFS file system

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, debian, ntfs

I have an NTFS partition that I need to share with Windows that is on DualBoot on my computer, this partition now has 56GB free, but when I try to save anything on it, Linux says it's full due to reserving 5% of the blocks for the operational system.

I know that for ext* extensions I would use tune2fs to manage this buffer, but how would I manage this for an ntfs partition?

Today I use ntfs-3g for assembly.
The system running is Debian Bullseye (11)

Below are some screenshots of the space in use

[df -h output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISfxE.png)

[Gparted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwo9D.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extN reserves a percentage for *the root user* (and by extension, all system daemons which run as root). This a feature mostly specific to extN on Linux – most other filesystems actually do not have equivalent "root-only" reservations.

For most of its lifetime, NTFS also did not have any space reservation for "the OS". If the filesystem reports that it is full, then it is actually full.

A recent version of Windows 10 *did* introduce NTFS space reservation for Windows Update, which is only enabled for the system volume (not for all NTFS volumes).

The reserve in NTFS system volumes is fixed-size (approx. 7–8 GB) and not percentage-based. You can only control it through Windows, not through ntfs-3g yet.

- To check the reserve size:

  ```
  fsutil storagereserve query c:
  ```
- To check whether the reserve is enabled (Cmd and PowerShell):

  ```
  dism /online /Get-ReservedStorageState
  ```

  ```
  Get-WindowsReservedStorageState
  ```
- To disable the reserve (Cmd and PowerShell):

  ```
  dism /online /Set-ReservedStorageState /State:Disabled
  ```

  ```
  Set-WindowsReservedStorageState -State Disabled
  ```

Source: https://winbuzzer.com/2020/08/18/how-to-enable-or-disable-windows-10-reserved-storage-xcxwbt/

Comment: Wait, so what could be going on??? LOL
I updated the question with a print of the df command and gparted if you can give me a direction.
I looked in several places and couldn't find anything that would help me try a solution.
I needed to install some npm packages and I'm not getting it because of that. (By the way I can't save anything on the partition)

Comment: I try to check in Windows, but is only 4,5 GB reserved there.
Edit: But when I went back to linux I was able to save files without any problems, I think it must be some Windows mess.

Comment: @RodrigoTeixeiraAndreotti You need to learn about Fast Startup in Windows, why it's generally a good idea to disable it and, if dual-booting, a MUST. Also learn that writing to the Windows system partition from outside Windows is a bad idea and strongly discouraged.

Comment: I already have fast startup disabled on my Windows 10, that wasn't the problem. By the way, I haven't figured out what the problem was yet lol, I know the fact that I got into Windows and then restarted again in Debian eliminated the problem for now.